# Change Thread to Process in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks, process

in view of the fact that the library what use has a memory leak I would like to disregard my implementation from thread to process which I will be able to close and reopen the process after a specified time from start.

My implementation :

```
public class MyClass {

private MyClassAgent myClassAgent ;

private Thread mainThread;
private final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(false);

static {
    Webcam.setDriver(new MyCompositeDriver());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyClass().init("192.168.1.91", 2000, 0, 25);
    new MyClass().init("192.168.1.91", 2001, 10, 25);
}

    ...

public void init(String host, int port, int camera, Dimension dimension, int fps) {
    try {
        running.set(true);
        mainThread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (running.get()) {
                List<Webcam> webcamList = new ArrayList<Webcam>();
                for (Webcam webcam : Webcam.getWebcams())
                    if (!webcam.getName().contains("IP"))
                        webcamList.add(webcam);

                if (webcamList.size() > camera) {
                    Webcam webcam = webcamList.get(camera);
                    if (webcam.getLock().isLocked())
                        webcam.getLock().disable();
                    webcam.setViewSize(dimension);
                    webcam.open(true);

                    myClassAgent = new StreamingClientAgent(webcam, dimension, fps);
                    myClassAgent.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
                } else {
                    logger.info("Podana kamera nie istnieje");
                }
            }
        });
        mainThread.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("Blad w zwiazku z kamera : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void stop() {
    myClassAgent.stop();
    running.set(false);
}
}
```

How I can do this? I cant just close thread and reopen, because process in TaskManager still is and his memory is grow up.

Comment: You have a memory leak and your solution is to put your logic into its own process so that it can leak there and you can restart it if the leak is getting too big? How about... fixing the memory leak instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, the person responsible for the library I use does not respond. And this is a too complicated project that I could do myself. And because I need this library right now I wanted to do what I wrote above. Until I can contact the creator of the library.

Comment: The library seems to be well maintained and I don't see any open issues regarding memory leaks. Are you sure you are not simply incorrectly using the library and creating the memory leak on your side?

Comment: Example project with this library on authors page have memory leak too. I checked this, memory used by this process still grow up

Answer (score 0):

For starting an external process java platform gives you an [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

You have to specify command with arguments, like you are starting java application from command line. So the command is `java`, and arguments is `<jvm params like Xmx> -cp <classpath> <mainclass> <program arguments>`. To obtain a classpath you can use value of `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` - so process you create will have in classpath everything that you "parent" application have, so you could write code of child application right in your project:

```
public Process start() throws InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, IOException {
    final String cp = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp", cp, com.example.ExternalProcessMain.class.getName());
    builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT); //in case of std communication
    builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);  //in case of std communication
    return builder.start();  }
```

Next problem to solve is communication between parent and child processes. It could be done either through stdout either through socket. That will be easy if you need just to stream binary data from child process to parent process. If you need some complex communication like method call or something like that you have to implement some more complex solution. May be some messaging system, REST API, or custom protocol atop socket/stdin-out.

Finally you should control child process and not forget to terminate it. To avoid that in case parent process unexpectedly dies you could start thread in child process that will check that parent process still exist.